# Fundamental group of a space minus a point

Tags: general-topology, fundamental-groups

Suppose that two connected topological spaces, say $X $, $Y $, have the isomorphic fundamental groups. Is it true in general that, given two points $p\in X $, $q\in Y $, the fundamental groups of $X/\{p\} $ and $Y/\{q\} $ are isomorphic?

This question comes from this small exercise: given a function $f\in C^\infty $, defined from $S^3$ to $\mathbb {CP^1} $, show that a function $g\in C^\infty $ such that $f○g =\mathrm {Id}_{\mathbb {CP^1}}$ cannot exist. First off, the previous step of the exercise required to calculate the fundamental group of $\mathbb {CP^1} $ minus two points and the fundamental group of $S^3$ minus two points; plus, in the lectures we proved that $S^2$ and $S^3$ aren't homeomorphic by showing that  $S^2$ minus two points and $S^3$ minus two points have different fundamental groups.

Now, if the answer to the question above is yes, if such a $g $ exists, $\mathbb {CP^1} $ and $S^3$ are homeomorphic, and so the fundamental groups should be isomorphic. However since the fundamental group of $\mathbb {CP^1} $ minus two points and the fundamental group of $S^3$ minus two points are respectively $\mathbb Z $ and $\{0\} $, this is absurd. If the answer is no, I would like to know why the example about $S^2$ and $S^3$ makes sense, and maybe a hint for the exercise. Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, it’s not automatic. Take eg $X=\mathbb{R}^2$, $Y=\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: It's not even true for $X=Y$

Comment: 'algebraic-geometry' also isn't an appropriate tag for this question.

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti could you make an example of path-connected space $X $ such that $\pi (X/\{p\})\neq\pi (X/\{q\})$ for some points $p,q\in X $? Thanks

Comment: @Dorian take a circle with a closed segment sticking out. If you remove the endpoint of the segment you get a space homotopy equivalent to a circle, if you remove a point on the circle you get a space which is contractible

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti so for example take the circle $C $ with a segment $S $ sticking out, and call $p $ the point of intersection of $C $ and $S $. If I remove a point, I can obtain three classes of homeomorphic spaces: namely, I can remove a point of $S/\{p\} $ , of $C/\{p\} $ , or I can remove $p $. Is there a rigorous way to generalize this? Actually, I would say that given a topological space $X $, then $X /\{x\}$ and  $X/\{y\}$ are homeomorphic iff there is a homeomorphism $\phi: X\to X $ such that  $\phi (x)=y $. I'm not sure that the "only if" holds; is the rest correct? Thanks a lot

Comment: What you're looking for is the concept of a homogeneous space

Comment: Thank you, actually homogeneous spaces are not in the program but I'll give them a look